How to reload on same tab after deletion
I have two tabs on a page and when I delete something from the second tab the page reloads and goes back to the first tab. I need help on how to keep it on the second tab after deletion.
This is the html for the tab group:
<div class="card-header" *ngIf="!loading">
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="changeActiveTab($event)">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of topTabs" [label]="tab">
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
</div>

and the delete is an action on a menu that calls the delete function on a click event
 <mat-menu #rowActions>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="navigate(['/app/violations/detail/' 
      + violation.id])">View
                    </button>
                    <button *ngIf="hasWriteAccess" mat-menu-item 
      (click)="deleteViolation(violation)">Delete
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>

Typescript
 export class UnitViolationListComponent implements OnInit, 
    AfterViewInit
  {
      @Input() unitId: number = null;
      @Input() unit: Unit;

  searchValue: string = '';

  // Tabs
  port class UnitViolationListComponent implements OnInit, 
  AfterViewInit
 {
 @Input() unitId: number = null;
 @Input() unit: Unit;

 searchValue: string = '';

// Tabs
activeTab: string = 'All Outstanding';
topTabs: string [] = [
    'All Outstanding',
    'Completed',
];

downloadingPdf: boolean = false;

tags: any[] = [];
unitTags: any[] = [];
unitOrgTags: Tag[];

completeViolations: ViolationStatement[] = [];
notCompleteViolations: ViolationStatement[] = [];
violations: ViolationStatement[] = [];

tableDataSource: MatTableDataSource<ViolationStatement> = new 
                 MatTableDataSource<ViolationStatement>();
displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'unit',
    'title',
    'createdAt',
    'resolutionTime',
    'completedTime',
    'actions',
];
pageSizeOptions: number[] = [
    25,
    50,
    100,
    200,
];
orgViolationStatuses: ViolationStatus[] = [];
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) matpaginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

// Component State
uploading: boolean = false;
loading: boolean = true;

hasWriteAccess: boolean = false;

_jwt: JwtLegFiClaims;

constructor(
        private _dialog: MatDialog,
        private _fb: FormBuilder,
        private _growler: GrowlerService,
        private _router: Router,
        private _scrollService: ScrollService,
        private _violationsService: ViolationsService,
        private _csvExportService: CsvExportService,
) {
}

async ngOnInit() {
    this._scrollService.scrollToTop();
    this._jwt = LegFiJwtService.read();

    this.hasWriteAccess = 
   LegFiJwtService.doesUserHaveModulePermission(
            'violation',
            true,
    );

    if (this.unitId) {
        this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns.filter(c => 
 c !== 'unit');
    }

    if (this._jwt !== null) {
        if (this._jwt.superUser || this._jwt.admin) {
            this.hasWriteAccess = true;
        }
    }

    await this.getOrgViolationStatuses();
    this.getUnitViolations();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tableDataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.tableDataSource.paginator = this.matpaginator;

    const originalFilterFunction = 
    this.tableDataSource.filterPredicate;
    this.tableDataSource.filterPredicate = (data: 
     ViolationStatement) => {
        // and lastly filter on the text string if provided
        if (originalFilterFunction(data.unit as any, 
         this.searchValue)) {
            return true;
        }

        return originalFilterFunction(data, this.searchValue);
    };
}

/** Get the available statuses for violations for this org */
async getOrgViolationStatuses() {
    await this._violationsService
            .getViolationStatusesPromise()
            .then(
                    async (statuses: ViolationStatus[]) => {
                        this.orgViolationStatuses = statuses;
                        if (this.orgViolationStatuses.length) {
                            
        this.displayedColumns.unshift('status');

                            // redo the top tabs w custom status
                            this.topTabs = [
                                'All Outstanding',
                                ...this.orgViolationStatuses.map(s 
        => s.title),
                                'Completed',
                            ];
                        }
                    },
                    (err: any) => {
                        console.error('cant get template: ', err);
                    },
            );
}

parseTableDataByStatus() {
    if (this.activeTab === 'Completed') {
        this.tableDataSource.data = this.completeViolations;
    } else if (this.activeTab === 'All Outstanding') {
        this.tableDataSource.data = this.notCompleteViolations;
    } else if (this.orgViolationStatuses.length) {
        this.tableDataSource.data = 
      this.notCompleteViolations.filter(s => {
            return s.status === this.activeTab;
        });
    }
   }

  getUnitViolations() {
     this.loading = true;

     this._violationsService
            .getUnitViolations(null, this.unitId)
            .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
            .subscribe(async (violations: ViolationStatement[]) => 
   {
                this.completeViolations = violations.filter(v => 
       v.completedTime);
                this.notCompleteViolations = violations.filter(v 
   => !v.completedTime);

                this.parseTableDataByStatus();

                this.updateFilter();
                this.loading = false;
            }, () => {
                this.loading = false;
                this._growler.error('Error', 'There was an error 
      loading violations for this unit.');
            });
}

/**
 * Trigger a re-filter when any of the things we filter by change
 */
updateFilter() {
    this.tableDataSource.filter = this.searchValue;
    if (this.tags.length > 0) {
        this.tableDataSource.filter += '//TAGS//';
    }
    if (this.unitTags.length > 0) {
        this.tableDataSource.filter += '//UNITTAGS//';
    }
}

changeActiveTab(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.activeTab = event.tab.textLabel;

    // hide the 'completed' column in the table if we are not on 
     the 'completed' tab
    if (this.activeTab === 'Completed') {
        this.displayedColumns = [
            'unit',
            'title',
            'createdAt',
            'resolutionTime',
            'completedTime',
            'actions',
        ];
    } else {
        this.displayedColumns = [
            'unit',
            'title',
            'createdAt',
            'resolutionTime',
            'actions',
        ];
    }

    if (this.unitId) {
        this.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns.filter(c => 
   c !== 'unit');
    }

    if (this.orgViolationStatuses.length) {
        this.displayedColumns.unshift('status');
    }

    this.parseTableDataByStatus();
    this.updateFilter();
}

/**
 * Navigate to Request Detail Page
 * @param {any[]} routerLink
 */
navigate(routerLink: any[]) {
    if (this._jwt !== null) {
        // noinspection JSIgnoredPromiseFromCall
        this._router.navigate(routerLink);
    }
}

deleteViolation(violation: ViolationStatement) {
    const baseDialog = 
  this._dialog.open(ConfirmDeleteModalComponent, {
        width: MatDialogSizes.XS,
        data: 'violation',
    });

    baseDialog.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmation: boolean) => 
  {
        if (confirmation) {
            this._violationsService
                    .deleteViolation([violation.id])
                    .subscribe(() => {
                        this.getUnitViolations();
                    });
        }
    });
 }

exportCsv() {
    const c = this.tableDataSource.filteredData.map((v: 
  ViolationStatement) => {
        return new ViolationExportListItem(v);
    });

    const options = {
        headers: [
            'status',
            'unit',
            'title',
            'message',
            'created',
            'resolveBy',
            'completed',
            'address',
            'city',
            'state',
            'zip',
            'comments',
        ],
        showLabels: true,
    };

    this._csvExportService.generateCsv(c, 'violation-export', 
  options);
}

exportPdf() {
    this.downloadingPdf = true;
    this._violationsService.getUnitViolationListPdf(this.unitId, 
    this.activeTab)
            .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
            .subscribe(
                    response => {
                        
      this._csvExportService.downloadFile(response, (this.unitId
                                ? this.unitId + '-'
                                : '') + this.activeTab + '- 
          violations.pdf', 'application/pdf');

                        this.downloadingPdf = false;
                    },
                    () => {
                        this.downloadingPdf = false;
                    },
            );
}

/**
 * Handle Toggle of Modals
 * @param {boolean} state
 * @param {string} modal
 */
toggleModal(state: boolean, modal: string) {
    this[modal] = state;
  }

}
Is this is something that can be done on the delete function in TS or is there more needed? That is where I need help.

What does the method this.getUnitViolations() do? Get request for all tabs? And where do you define the active tab?

Added getUnitViolations() function which filters the tabs and yes gets request all the tabs. I also added where the active tab is defined.

And when else is the variable activeTab filled? In the changeActiveTab()? Please share this code also…

You need to keep track of the active tab, or try moving the ngif, the "if" is refreshing the tab component every time. Perhaps moving the ngIf to inside the content of each tab could help you.

@SwissCodeMen I put the entire typescript code in my post.

With the whole typescript I see, that the variable activeTab in the method changeActiveTab() is set: this.activeTab = event.tab.textLabel;. To detect what this event delivers to set the variable activeTab, I would console.log(event.tab.textLabel); it. Delivers the event tab1 when should staying on tab2, you know where you must handle the misconduct. Then show also the code from mat-tab-group.

When an element is toggled into view using ngIf, it gets removed completely when the condition is false, unlike hiding the element using CSS (reference). In your code, getUnitViolations is called inside of your deleteViolation function, which then resets the loading flag, causing your tab group to be removed from the DOM and then re-added.
Some options would be to refactor how you handle loading in the UI or to set selectedIndex on the tab group to control which tab displays.

I think the solution is not to pass the fixed value ([selectedIndex][2]) to stay on tab 2. But 2 would be anyway wrong, because the array indexing starts at 0 and would be at 1 for the second entry)

the 2 was a formatting issue w/ linking to material docs, updated the answer

@India Evans What am I setting selectedIndex to in the tab group? There's two tabs and when I delete I want to stay on the current tab.

with 0-based indexing, the second tab would equate to index 1. So setting selectedIndex="1" should set the second tab as active. Rather than hardcoding a specific tab however, you could add a prop to track the last active tab and set it to that, e.g.selectedIndex="lastActiveTab"
